# To whom did Jaime Lannister lose on a previous tournament that people talk about in season one and what was the tournament honoring?

Tags: game-of-thrones

To whom did Jaime Lannister lose on a previous tournament that people talk about in season one and what was the tournament honoring?

Comment: As a note, it's probably more productive to ask about the books since the volume of material just makes it more likely that this was explained in detail there. I do not believe it was mentioned again in the show.

Answer (score 15):

The only tournament of note that Jaime participated in (and was mentioned in the TV series) was the one where he lost to Loras Tyrell. It's the tournament that Littlefinger claims he lost the Dragonbone dagger to Tyrion for betting on Jaime.

According to the [Wiki of Ice and Fire](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/History_of_Tourneys_in_Westeros) the tournament was in honor of Prince Joffrey's 12th name day.

Answer (score 10):

I'm going to hazard an educated guess and say that you're talking about the tourney that Jaime lost to Loras Tyrell.  This was only of note because Petyr's dagger (implicated in the attempted murder of Bran and assault of Catelyn) was allegedly lost to Tyrion because of the upset.

I don't believe we were given many more details on the tourney than that, i.e. who it was in honour of.

Comment: I think the fact that Jaime lost was relatively noteworthy itself, though not in terms of the overall storyline.

Comment: Attempted murder of _Bran_ you mean; Catelyn was merely in the wrong place at the wrong time.

Comment: Cheers, you're right.  I remembered Catelyn's injuries, I forgot Bran was the actual target.